# Convergence in mean of differentiated Fourier series

Tags: fourier-series, harmonic-analysis

Let a function $f: \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be integrable on $[-\pi,\pi]$ and $2\pi$-periodic. Let 
$$
\frac{a_0}{2}+\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty (a_n \cos nx+b_n \sin nx)
$$ be the Fourier series of $f$.

Assume that $f$ has continuous derivative at $a$. How to show that  of partial sum $T_n$ of the series 
$$
\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty (-n a_n \sin nx+n b_n \cos nx)
$$ 
(it is the Fourier series of $f$ after termwise differentiation) is convergent in arithmetic mean in $a$  to $f'(a)$? That is
$$
\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\sigma_n(x):=\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\frac{T_0(a)+T_1(a)+\ldots +T_{n-1}(a)}{n-1} = f'(a)
$$
Thanks.

Comment: Do you know that, if $f$ is continuous, while the Fourier series of $f$ may not converge to $f$, the series of arithmetic means will converge uniformly to $f$? This is knows as Fejér's theorem. This question looks like a localized version of this result for $f'$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $g$ be $2\pi$-periodic function from $C^1(\mathbb T)$ coinciding with $f$ in some neighborhood of $a$. According to the [Riemann localization principle](http://books.google.ru/books?id=tlLE4KUkk1gC&pg=PA31&lpg=PA31&dq=the%20Riemann%20localization%20principle&source=bl&ots=KL1maocfy7&sig=sqmeX3ghTjXwkjuPXrtm4g-27wg&hl=ru&sa=X&ei=85vlT5rlF4-E-waT1dCaCg&ved=0CEwQ6AEwAA#v=onepage&q=the%20Riemann%20localization%20principle&f=false) difference of partial Fourier sums $\Delta T_n(a)$ for $f'$ and $g'$ tends to zero:
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty}\Delta T_n(a)=\lim_{n\to\infty}(T_n^f(a)-T_n^g(a))=0.
$$
It follows that 
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty}
\frac{\Delta T_0(a)+\Delta T_1(a)+\ldots +\Delta T_{n-1}(a)}{n}=0.
$$
By Fejér's theorem 
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty}
\frac{T_0^g(a)+T_1^g(a)+\ldots +T_{n-1}^g(a)}{n}=g'(a)=f'(a),
$$
so 
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty}
\frac{T_0^f(a)+T_1^f(a)+\ldots +T_{n-1}^f(a)}{n}=f'(a)
$$
too.